# Get Apple Watch battery percentage on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, apple-watch

I would like to build an iPhone app that shows the battery percentage of the Apple Watch. With iOS 10 in the widgets I can see this rate but somehow I would like to get this number in my own app. Is there any way? (in Swift)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel
```

You can try this, it return a Float from AppleWatch code. You can send this var as data between watch/iPhone

Comment: But I would like it to do that without using apple watch app. I guess there is no way to get that data in background without any interact by users

Comment: I guess you can get data in background by create a UIBackgroundTask, but the app must be launch.